# How to take a string "str" and understand that it is datatype:str

Tags: python, yaml

I've a Yaml file, in which I'm denoting the columns and datatypes of a CSV. I'll be using this to read a dataframe. The file is of format:

```
columns:
    company: str
    country: str
    address: str
```

When I read the yaml file, I'll get:

```
{
    "columns": {
        { "company": "str"},
        { "country": "str"},
        { "address": "str"}
    }
}
```

But I need it as:

```
    "columns": {
        { "company": str},
        { "country": str},
        { "address": str}
    }
}
```

At this point, my hack is to use a look up table that converts into type.

```
{ 
    "int": int, 
    "str": str
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`import builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) and get types as attributes of this module:

```
import builtins

config['columns'] = {k: getattr(builtins, v) for k, v in config['columns'].items()}
```